# Does there already exist a Python (2.7) module that will execute a flex-produced lexer?

Tags: python-2.7, lex, flex-lexer

I tried Plex, which is a pure-Python implementation of flex.  It works, but for large input files (10-100+ MB) it is very slow.  Most of the time is spent in the lexer.  So I wish to use flex to produce the lexer in C, and call it from within Python.  I'm rather surprised I can't find one, but when I google, I always end up with either lexers written in C to lex Python text, or lexers written in Python to lex C text.

Failing that, can anybody suggest a straightforward way to turn the Flex C code into an extension?

Comment: What about PLY? http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Comment: @PedroWerneck As I read it, PLY as written in Python.  1st bullet-point on that page: "It's implemented entirely in Python."  That's unlikely to be significantly faster than Plex, which is also implemented in Python.  I want the speed of C for the lexer, but the flexibility of Python for using it.

Comment: Well... good luck finding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only such module is [FlexBisonModule-2.0](http://www.crsr.net/files/FBModule.html).  It does indeed take the output of Flex and/or Bison and turn them into Python modules.  Unfortunately, it's rather ancient (last modified March of 2002), and was developed for Python 1.5.2 & 2.0.  I'll have to examine it to see if it needs updated to Python 2.7.6, or even 3.x.

I have just discovered another possibility: [PyBison 0.1.8](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pybison/).  You have to turn your .l and .y files into it's preferred form, and define some Python methods.  It then invokes flex & bison, creating a Python parser class for you.  It says it works on Linux and possible BSD-based systems.  It dates from 2004.